# Source Engine entity access sharing

Tags: portal-2, source-engine

In Source games you can directly (with cheats enabled) access the entity network of each map through such commands as "ent_text" and "ent_fire". However, even with cheats enabled, only the first player is able to do this. The other player does not have access to the entity network with the same commands. Is there any way to allow other players access to this network in the same way?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is because the first player is the one hosting the game. Only the host has access to the engine like that. Source does not support firing outputs on entities directly over the network.

So unfortunately, no, there is no way for the second player to use `ent_fire`.